# PayPal reference transaction- status code 400 in response

Tags: php, paypal

I try to use PayPal Reference Transactin. I have already made a billing agreemet, got the Billing Agreement ID set up before any transaction is done.

I make a simple transaction request, but got:

> PPConnectionException in PPHttpConnection.php line 108: 
>   
>   Got Http response code 400 when accessing
>   https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0.

My code (writte in Laravel 5.3 with merchant-sdk-php package):

```
$user=Auth::user();

$currencyCode = 'GBP';
$price=config('constants.offer_submit_price');

$reference_id=$user->userExt()->where('field_name', '=', 'billing_agreement')->firstOrFail()->field_value;
$amount = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, $price);

$paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
$paymentDetails->OrderTotal = $amount;

$RTRequestDetails = new DoReferenceTransactionRequestDetailsType();
$RTRequestDetails->PaymentDetails = $paymentDetails;
$RTRequestDetails->ReferenceID = $reference_id;
$RTRequestDetails->PaymentAction ='sale';

$RTRequest = new DoReferenceTransactionRequestType();
$RTRequest->DoReferenceTransactionRequestDetails  = $RTRequestDetails;

$RTReq = new DoReferenceTransactionReq();
$RTReq->DoReferenceTransactionRequest = $RTRequest;

$paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService($this->config);
try {
    $setRTResponse = $paypalService->DoReferenceTransaction($RTReq);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    dd($ex);
}
```

Thats the SAOP envelopr produced by script:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" >
    <soapenv:Header>
    <ns:RequesterCredentials>
    <ebl:Credentials>
        <ebl:Username>username
</ebl:Username>
<ebl:Password>password
</ebl:Password>
<ebl:Signature>signature
</ebl:Signature>
</ebl:Credentials>
</ns:RequesterCredentials>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns:DoReferenceTransactionReq>
    <ns:DoReferenceTransactionRequest>
    <ebl:DoReferenceTransactionRequestDetails>
    <ebl:ReferenceID>B-reference_id
</ebl:ReferenceID>
<ebl:PaymentAction>sale
</ebl:PaymentAction>
<ebl:PaymentDetails>
    <ebl:OrderTotal currencyID="GBP">10
</ebl:OrderTotal>
<ebl:ButtonSource>PayPal_SDK
</ebl:ButtonSource>
</ebl:PaymentDetails>
</ebl:DoReferenceTransactionRequestDetails>
<ebl:Version>106.0
</ebl:Version>
</ns:DoReferenceTransactionRequest>
</ns:DoReferenceTransactionReq>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'
```

Comment: huehuehuehuehue

Answer (score 1):

With help of my friend I have figured out what was wrong.

```
$RTRequestDetails->PaymentAction ='Sale';
```

instead of

```
$RTRequestDetails->PaymentAction ='sale';
```

PayPal SOAP API need to have everything in right case sensitive.
Regret, they don't send any info what's wrong.